# How to keep a reference of PictureBox Image attached to a variable and not to an object of the variable?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I work in C# and want to keep a reference of PictureBox.Image attached to a variable and not to an object of the variable. That means I want freely change the objects of this variable and PictureBox will always refers to the variable.

I have a class that manipulates images, merges them and returns image `ImageShow` to visualize in PictureBox. Often I have to assign new Image object to a variable. When I do so, PictureBox keeps the old object, while I want it to take a new one.

```
class Foo
{
   Image ImageShow = null;

   public void FooFunc()
   {
      //some code
      changeImageSize(new Size(600,800))
   }

   private void changeImageSize(Size newSize)
   {
      if(ImageShow != null)
         ImageShow.Dispose();
      ImageShow = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
   }
}
```

When I do a code like this:

```
var obj = Foo();
obj.SetImage(new Bitmap(50,50));
pictureBox.Image = obj.GetImage();
obj.FooFunc();
```

PictureBox keeps the destroyed old Image object. So I get an error if I try to do anything with PictureBox.

Returning a new image object every time creates to many dependencies between internal code of the class and PictureBox. So it is not the best solution for me.

Simple example:

```
Image img;

img = new Bitmap(200, 200);
pictureBox1.Image = img;

img = new Bitmap(300, 300);
```

Picturebox continues to refer to the old image

`pictureBox1.Image.Size = {Width = 200 Height = 200}`

While I want in to refers to the `img` variable and new object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either look into Binding the `Image` property of the `PictureBox` using `PictureBox.Bindings.Add()` and making an object to bind to that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that when you set the image property for that object the Picturebox updates - or, much more simply, you can encapsulate `ImageShow` in a property and add the logic to update the picturebox to the setter.

```
private Image _imageShow = null;
public Image ImageShow {
    get {
        return _imageShow
    }
    set {
        _imageShow = value;
        pictureBox1.Image = value;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you set `ImageShow` to a new image, the `PictureBox` will be set to the same image.

The reason your code doesn't work as-is is because `ImageShow` is storing a reference to the `Image`, and setting `pictureBox1.Image` sets the property to a reference to the same `Image` - but if you change what `ImageShow` is referencing the `PictureBox` will never see that, as it is referencing the original image, not the field `ImageShow`.